# get output text from terminal and save it in local machine (windows server)

Tags: terminal

i used terminal package in automation anywhere and I want to get the output in my machine (windows server)
and i did --command > "D:\123.txt" and didnot get the output in location.

so any help.

i excepect to get the output in my local machine not in terminal